# react-native build fail

Tags: react-native

**MY OS = Windows 10**

**IDE = VS Code**

**react-native info**

System:

```
OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz    
Memory: 7.00 GB / 11.89 GB
```

Binaries:

```
Node: 13.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.14.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
```

SDKs:

```
Android SDK: Not Found
```

IDEs:

```
Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6308749
```

Languages:

```
Python: 2.7.17
```

npmPackages:

```
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
react-native: 0.62.0 => 0.62.0
```

npmGlobalPackages:

```
*react-native*: Not Found
```

//////////////// **Path** /////////////////

[PATH Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoSTO.png)

//////////////// **Build Fail Message** ///////////////////

*react-native run-android*

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIgK5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 things from the errors:

- The path shows that gradle installed somewhere using OneDrive. Installing stuff like gradle on a cloud environment is never a smart idea. You should install this somewhere on your main windows drive, let's say C: drive.
- Make sure that you have Android Studio installed. Without it cannot run.

If you want to share code with other users try GitHub. Sharing code using OneDrive is not a working solution.

Comment: OneDrive :( Mistake